# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error: Why do I get an HTTP error 400 on the ESP32 board?

Tags: arduino, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, arduino-esp32, chatgpt-api

I was planning to make a project to receive the response given by chatgpt to my ESP32 board for a given text. I tried the following, but after connecting to the WiFi, the serial plotter shows the message HTTP error 400. I double-checked the API key, and it was perfectly OK. Can you please tell me where I got it wrong?

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* password = "password";
const char* apiKey = "api";

const char* userMessage = "Hey there ! how are you ?";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);

  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");

  // Prepare the JSON payload
  DynamicJsonDocument payload(1024);
  payload["model"] = "gpt-3.5-turbo";
  
  JsonArray messages = payload.createNestedArray("messages");
  
  JsonObject systemMessage = messages.createNestedObject();
  systemMessage["role"] = "system";
  systemMessage["content"] = "You are a helpful assistant.";
  
  JsonObject userMessageObject = messages.createNestedObject();
  userMessageObject["role"] = "user";
  userMessageObject["content"] = userMessage;

  // Serialize the JSON payload
  String payloadStr;
  serializeJson(payload, payloadStr);

  // Send the request to the OpenAI API
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin("https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/gpt-3.5-turbo/completions");
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  http.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + String(apiKey));
  
  int httpResponseCode = http.POST(payloadStr);
  
  if (httpResponseCode == 200) {
    String response = http.getString();
    Serial.println("API Response:");
    Serial.println(response); // Print the API response
  } else {
    Serial.println("HTTP Error: " + String(httpResponseCode));
  }

  http.end();
}

void loop() {
}
```

I was expecting to see the response to my text from the OpenAI API, but it returned an HTTP error 400. I am not getting where it went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

All [Engines API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations/2022-06-03-legacy-endpoints) endpoints are deprecated.

[image: Deprecated]

#### Solution

Use the [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api) endpoint.

Change the URL from this...

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/gpt-3.5-turbo/completions
```

...to this.

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions
```

Comment: Now another issue arises. At this point, whatever input i give to it, It always returns either null or HTTP error -11. what to do now ?

Comment: @user3793520 How *either*? Sometimes work and sometimes not? This is very strange.  It would be more normal to **always** get `null` or an error.

Comment: @user3793520, error -11 is read timeout. The website requires an HTTPS access, your code is using the plain non-secure http client. Please check the [BasicHttpsClient](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/HTTPClient/examples) example (it is accessible from your Arduino IDE File->Examples-><your board>) on how to setup a secure client.